# Save map with Qtlocation

Tags: qt, dictionary, location

I use Qt and `QtLocation` to display a map but I need internet access in order to download it.I would like to be able to display the maps when I am not connected to the internet.

Is it possible to save the Qt Location map on my computer? Has someone have already used that API in offline mode?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the official qtlocation plugins have an offline disk cache.
Most of QtLocation plugins currently (5.8) allow you to configure such cache size.
One (OSM) also allows you to specify an "offline tile directory", which, however, you have to manually populate.